# Why does Scala need to add Scala version to libraries?

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I am looking into Scala projects, I saw Scala version is adding to libraries both to project achieved libraries and public libraries. I am interested in:

1. Is there any benefit of it or just a convention?
2. Is it anything particular to Scala version? By this I mean whether Scala has any registry that for this version of Scala you should use this version of particular public library (Akka, Scala Test or any majorly supporting by Scala).

I am **migrating my existing Scala Akka project from 10.x to 11.x**. So, I should deeply understand all these things. I search on net for **Migration Scala 10.x to 11.x** but I did not find any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the cross-building convention append the scala version to the artifactId?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122139/why-does-the-cross-building-convention-append-the-scala-version-to-the-artifacti)

Answer (score 1):

It's because Scala versions are not binary compatible between versions. For this reason, libraries publish the same version for different Scala versions.
Each library version used in your project should be the one compiled for the Scala version you use.

Comment: No. The middle number is the major version. the first the epic. the third the minor. there are additionally patch revesions as well.

Comment: Had a confusion about version numbers. Removed it from the answer.

Comment: But Scsla releases are both binary forward, and backwards, within major version.

Comment: @ViktorKlang The question refers to scala 2.10 and 2.11, those ones were not binary compatible, right?